# Calculate the new position of a rotated rectangle by the corner

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, angle, rectangles

I am trying to calculate the new position of a rotated rectangle around the center.
But it is rotated by moving the bottom right corner upwards.
Here is an example.

[image]

The rectangle is moved by dragging the right bottom corner upwards, but the rectangle is rotated around its center.

[image]

So my question is :
How to find the new position of the right bottom corner of the rectangle after rotation ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate the rectangle so that the center is the origin, and then apply the appropriate rotation matrix. Let's say the rectangle has width $w$ and height $h$. Then if we translate so that the center is the origin, then the bottom right corner is now the point $\left( \frac{w}{2}, \, -\frac{h}{2} \right)$. Let's say you want to rotate counterclockwise by angle $\theta$. Then multiply by the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right)$ to do the rotation. The new rotated point is then:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} w \\ -h \end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{array}{c} w\cos(\theta) + h\sin(\theta) \\ w\sin(\theta) - h\cos(\theta) \end{array}\right) $$

So the new rotated point is $\left( \frac{w\cos(\theta)+h\sin(\theta)}{2}, \, \frac{2\sin(\theta)-h\cos(\theta)}{2}\right)$. Now just translate back to the original position. If the center of the rectangle was $(a,b)$, then add $(a,b)$ to the point we got above.